# RelaxNG: <choice> containing <zeroOrMore>

Tags: xml, validation, relaxng

In RelaxNG, I want to describe a structure similar to this:

```
<parent>
    <subelem1>
    <subelem1>
    <subelem1>
    ...
</parent>
```

or:

```
<parent>
    <subelem2>
    <subelem2>
    <subelem2>
    ...
</parent>
```

I tried with the following rng:

```
<rng:element name="parent">
    <rng:choice>
        <rng:zeroOrMore>
            <rng:ref name="subelem1"/>
        </rng:zeroOrMore>
        <rng:zeroOrMore>
            <rng:ref name="subelem2"/>
        </rng:zeroOrMore>
    </rng:choice>
</rng:element>
```

But verifying with `lxml` in Python, I only get error messages `Did not expect element subelem1 there`.

What's wrong there?

Comment: Actually the above code works thanks to Nic Gibson's Edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a slightly different schema to yours but it should be functionality the same:

```
<rng:grammar 
    xmlns:rng="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
    xmlns:a="http://relaxng.org/ns/compatibility/annotations/1.0"
    datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">
    <rng:start>
        <rng:ref name="dparent"/>
    </rng:start>

    <rng:define name="dparent">
    <rng:element name="parent">
        <rng:choice>
            <rng:zeroOrMore>
                <rng:element name="subelem2">
                    <rng:empty/>
                </rng:element>
            </rng:zeroOrMore>
            <rng:zeroOrMore>
                <rng:element name="subelem1">
                    <rng:empty/>
                </rng:element>
            </rng:zeroOrMore>
        </rng:choice>
    </rng:element>

    </rng:define>
```

That validates both your sample documents just fine using [jing](https://code.google.com/p/jing-trang/) and also with [xmllint](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) (which uses libxml2 as does lxml in python if I remember correctly). I'd suggest comparing your full grammar (I assume you only posted part of it) with the above. Also, I corrected your namespaces (the `choice` element wasn't in one). If you still can't validate I would suggest hte problem is with `lxml` rather than the grammar.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit - I also had no namespace for the choice element in my rng...

Comment: That would be the problem then :)